# Response.Redirect not working onloggedin event

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am creating a SignIn page with Login control. I want page to be redirect to another page once it got authenticated. But it redirecting me to home page.(home.aspx). Strange. Please advise.

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="ValidateUser" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" DestinationPageUrl="~/DonationForm.aspx">
    </asp:Login>

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userId = 0;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }
            switch (userId)
            {
                case -1:
                    Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                    break;
                default:
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }



    protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/DonationForm.aspx");
    }
```

}

Comment: <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="ValidateUser" OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" DestinationPageUrl="~/DonationForm.aspx">
    </asp:Login>

Comment: Have you used Forms authentication ? Can you paste the portion of code from web.config ?

Comment: Its started working for me. I changed defaulturl="~DonationForm.aspx"<System.web><authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/DonationForm.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal behavior for the **FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage** method you have in the switch statement.  It redirects back to the page that originally directed to the login page.  You can see the page name in the **ReturnUrl** QueryString value while viewing the login page.

If you want to redirect to another page try changing the default block of the switch statement to

```
default:
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
    Response.Redirect("~/DonationForm.aspx"); 
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you want to use **LoggingIn** event, because you are validating user by yourself instead of relying on **Membership Provider**.

If you use the following **LoggingIn** event, you do not need **ValidateUser** and **LoggedIn** events.

```
protected void Login1_LoggingIn(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 0;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
        ["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();
        }
        switch (userId)
        {
            case -1:
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                break;
            case -2:
                Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                break;
            default:
                // RedirectFromLoginPage will take care of creating 
                // authentication cookie and redirect; you do not need 
                // to do anything.
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(
                    Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> I want page to be redirect to another page once it got authenticated.
>   But it redirecting me to home page.(home.aspx). Strange.

If you want a user to redirect to a page, you can set the [defaultUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl(v=vs.110).aspx) in web.config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/DonationForm.aspx" />
</authentication>
```