# ASP.net The name 'userName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've clicked over 20 links trying to solve this problem in different websites.

Please help me

So I am trying to do a simple log in authentication.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class Account_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
    {

    }
}
}
```

But an error message pops up saying "The name 'userName' does not exist in the current context' and The name 'Password' does not exist in the current context.

Here is the aspx code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Account_Login" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
</hgroup>
<section id="loginForm">
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FailureText" />
            </p>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Log in Form</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="RememberMe" />
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="checkbox">Remember me?</asp:Label>
                    </li>
                </ol>
                <asp:Button ID="loginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log in" OnClick="loginButton_Click" />
            </fieldset>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
    <p>
        <a href="Register.aspx">Register</a>
        if you don't have an account.
    </p>
</section>
```

Please help me :)

Comment: The ID is UserName not userName...

Comment: Oops, sorry I was testing if camel casing affected it. But it didn't and forgot to change the value. 

But I still get the same error, thank you:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UserName** is inside **Login** control, so you need to access it via **Login1** control.

```
string userName = Login1.UserName;
string password = Login1.Password;
```

Another problem in your code is, you should not use **loginButton_Click** event if you use **Login** control.

In stead, you need to use the following depending on your satiation -

- LoggingIn
- LoggedIn

Comment: Hey Win :) I have tried it that way

        string userName = Login1.UserName;
        string password = Login1.Password; 

             if(FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, password))
             {

             }

But I get the error message

Comment: `if(FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, password)) {` is not valid statement. **RedirectFromLoginPage's return type** is **void**, so it doesn't return anything. Refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25654827/296861) in my comment.

Comment: @helloGoodDay Based on your comments in other answers, are you trying to implement **Form Authentication** or **Membership Provider**? Form Authentication is a subset of Membership Provider. Either way they are totally different from your original question; they are huge topic, and they cannot be answered in comment area. Please create a separate question if you have a question regarding - **Form Authentication** or **Membership Provider**.

Comment: you are right :) I changed it to FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(userName, password)) and it works now . Thank you so much. 

I'm trying to implement a Form Authentication

Answer (score 2):

C# is case sensitive.
it should be Username with a capital "U" as per your control ID:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
```

your code should be:

```
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT** - Noticed the control in question is within a usercontrol so the code should now be:

```
protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName.Text, Password.Text)
    {

    }
}
```

however you still did have a typo in the UserName ID

Comment: **UserName** Textbox is inside **Login** control. You cannot access it like that - **UserName.Text**. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25667546/296861

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Yup, I forgot to change the userName to UserName because I was testing if camel casing affected it. But it turned out it didn't. 

(Login1.UserName.Text, Password.Text) < If I do it that way within the parameters I get the error in Text for the Username field 'string' does not contain a definition for Text' and no extension method'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: @Ahmedilyas and Win I have changed it to Authenticate because the RedirectToLogin Arguments do not allow two strings within it at the same time. So I changed it to Authenticate

        string userName = Login1.UserName;
        string password = Login1.Password; 

             if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(userName, password))
             {

             }

That's how my code looks now. But I get the warning
'System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication(string,string)' is obsolete: "The recommended alternative is to use the Membership APIs, such as Membership.ValidateUser

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Code is case sensitive.

```
if(FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, Password.Text)
{

}
```