# Cannot access field ID from aspx to cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a asp.net web application whee in i am trying to build a simple login page having login.aspx and login.aspx.cs.

aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="nikeeWebApplication.Account.Login" culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" uiculture="auto" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" 
        RenderOuterTable="False" meta:resourcekey="LoginUserResource1">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" 
                meta:resourcekey="FailureTextResource1"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" 
                meta:resourcekey="LoginUserValidationSummaryResource1"/>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="login">
                    <legend>LOG IN</legend>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" 
                            meta:resourcekey="UserNameLabelResource1">Username:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry" 
                            meta:resourcekey="UserNameResource1"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" 
                            meta:resourcekey="UserNameRequiredResource1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password" 
                            meta:resourcekey="PasswordLabelResource1">Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" 
                            TextMode="Password" meta:resourcekey="PasswordResource1"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" 
                            meta:resourcekey="PasswordRequiredResource1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
                        ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup" 
                        meta:resourcekey="LoginButtonResource1"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Content>
```

cs page

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

namespace nikeeWebApplication.Account
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserMaster where UserName =@username and Password=@password", con);
            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Details.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i access the textbox from login page its giving the error.

The Image description is shown below. [image: .cs page]
[image: .aspx page]

Appreciate your help

Comment: For DataTable error, add - `using System.Data`

Comment: Please show all relevant code in your question instead of screenshots. Are the ASPX page and the codebehind in the same namespace?

Comment: For the DataTable error add using System.Data

Comment: Please show the full markup, because from the looks of it you have this inside of some type of template control.

Comment: My answer will work for you.

Comment: I think this is an exact duplicate of [ASP.net The name 'userName' does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666049/asp-net-the-name-username-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context). The textboxes are inside the `Login` control, so you need `LoginUser.UserName.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the textboxes like this:

```
TextBox Password = LoginUser.FindControl("Password") as TextBox;
TextBox UserName = LoginUser.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password.Text);
```

Or you could just use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", LoginUser.UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", LoginUser.Password);
```

And again, to get rid of the DataTable error add the using statement:

```
using System.Data;
```

Comment: No, you don't _need_ to. If you have a serverside control with an `ID`, a member with that ID gets generated for you.

Comment: So CodeCaster, then tell me why can't the codebehind see the controls? It is not doubt because the textboxes are nested within the LayoutTemplate.

Comment: If I'd have known and could be bothered to read through OP's code and post an answer, I would. Your answer is stating incorrectly that you _need_ to use `FindControl()`, which is easily proven to be false.

Comment: @thewisegod LoginUser.Password.Text is the correct way to access the content of password textbox and for username also.

Comment: I don't think you need the .Text and my way would still work.

Comment: You guys are correct for the LoginUser control, but let's say you add another control and you want to access it, the LoginControl is not going to know about it.